# PJSIP libsocket compile error

Tags: reference, undefined, symbols, pjsip

I get the following error when I try to compile the pjsip libraries in the Blackberry 10 IDE:

```
libpj-i486-pc-nto-qnx8.0.0.a(sock_bsd.o): undefined reference to symbol 'send@@libsocket.so.2'

'send@@libsocket.so.2' is defined in DSO /home/f3795594/bbndk/target_10_0_9_386/qnx6/x86/lib/libsocket.so.3 so try adding it to the linker command line
```

Has anybody come across this error? I know it's to do with the libsocket library but not sure where to begin.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple insertion into linking process:

Add the following library:

LIBS += /Applications/bbndk/target_10_0_9_386/qnx6/x86/lib/libsocket.so.3

My limited c compile knowledge got in the way.